# Обработка событий контекстного меню QWebView

Tags: webkit, qt, c++

В `QWebView` при клике правой кнопкой отображается контекстное меню с действиями над элементами веб-страницы.

Как можно задать реализацию для пунктов меню? Конкретно нужно заставить работать пункт "save image".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно, как и для любого `QWidget`.

Копать в сторону `QWidget::contextMenuEvent()`

можно добавить слот для обработки одного из `QAction`:

```
- QWebPage::OpenImageInNewWindow;
- QWebPage::DownloadImageToDisk;
- QWebPage::CopyImageToClipboard;
- QWebPage::CopyImageUrlToClipboard;
```

возвращаемых функцией `QWebView::pageAction(QWebPage::WebAction)`